# Detecting "schtasks /end" in C# console application

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I have a console application which I run as a scheduled task.

I want to have the ability to gracefully stop the scheduled task when running a deployment.

Our deployment process uses `schtasks /end` command to stop it.

How can I intercept this command in the C# application?

I tried to use `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` but it didn't got the event.

Thanks

Comment: You could use arguments of your own exe-file and some IPC, so that instead of `schtasks /end` you will call `myconsoleapp /end`. Bonus of using that approach is to have more control (to example, think of `myconsoleapp /autoupdate`).